# Why am I getting error 1118 here?

Tags: actionscript-3, compiler-errors

In the code below I have several MovieClips that are all TheBeetle(). They are in another MovieClip called gamelevel and also pushed in an array called bArray. previously I have indexed them in the gamelevel but after the event listener is called I cannot index them anymore and receive the error "1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject.". As the user clicks them, they die (and change the frame) and the dead body goes under other alive bodies, thats the reason I need to index them to 1 as they die. I understand what the error says but how can i do what i need to do?
The code works just fine but it wouldn't in the two lines i've mentioned in it, so take a look please:

```
public function clicked (event:MouseEvent)
    {
        if (event.target is TheBeetle && event.target.currentFrame <= 2)
        {
            var mc:Object = event.target

            // TheBeetle is actually a MovieClip but i cannot write: var mc:MovieClip = event.target, if i do i receive 1118


                if (mc.currentFrame == 1)
                {
                    mc.gotoAndStop (Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 4));
                }
                else
                {
                    mc.gotoAndStop (3);
                }
                mc.filters = null;

                // Here i need to index the TheBeetle as i did before like gamelevel.setChildIndex(mc,1) but i'd receive 1118!

                bArray.splice (bArray.indexOf(mc),1);

                if (bArray.length == 0)
                {
                    removeEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME,frameHandler);
                    waveTimer.removeEventListener (TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, changeLocation);
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly cast target to the MovieClip Class:

```
var mc:MovieClip = MovieClip(event.target);
```

You may need to do this BEFORE the line that checks target's currentFrame, as 'Object' doesn't have a currentFrame method.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use soft casting when you work with events and targets. By soft casting, if you have catched wrong target, you will not have problems - cast process simply returns `null`.

```
public function clicked (e:MouseEvent){
    var beetle: TheBeetle = e.target as TheBeetle;
    if(beetle != null && beetle.currentFrame <= 2){
        //Work with beetle as you want
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, isn't `TheBeetle(e.target)` equal to `e.target as TheBeetle`? If not, returning null is better than getting an exception.

Comment: They aren't equal. `TheBeetle(e.target)` will throw exception like TheBeetle@as6d54sad can't be casted to SomeAnotherClass@asd5fas5df. It's like strict cast, but such type of the cast, works faster.